# Fix double/single quote warning in visual studio code for Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have recently installed visual studio code and using it to write code in Flutter. But I am getting following warning in all import statements:

> Prefer double quotes where they won't require escape sequences.
>   dart(prefer_double_quotes)

There is no quick fix for it and when I change single quotes to double quotes I get warning for double quotes. Although it is not impacting my work but it makes my files look ugly with so many warnings. Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the [prefer_double_quotes lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_double_quotes.html). Check whether it's enabled for your project in the `analysis_options.yaml` file in the root of your project.

Comment: Hey @Danny, I searched everywhere but could only find JS/TS solutions to my problem. Do you have a clue how to change the default quote style from single to double in vscode + dart/flutter?

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella if you mean which quotes are used in generated code, I don't think that's configurable. I prefer double quotes (and use them in TS because single quotes look a little like backticks), but have found myself using single quotes for Dart.

Comment: Yeah, I meant generated, sorry about that. Thanks for your response, I guess I will keep single quotes than, the pros against having to change every import are not that worth.